# Creating references within XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that represents an article. I'm using client-side xslt to turn it into html for display.

I am trying to embed references throughout the xml file, and many of these references repeat. I was wondering if I can split the references out of the content part of the xml file and then link them together so that I'm not repeating myself many times.

I figured that I could add ID and IDREFs as attributes to the `<p>` and `<reference>` tags (using an XML Schema as namespaces will be important later). Thus:

```
<article>
  <body>
    <content>
      <p>This is the first paragraph.</p>
      <reference>Patrick</reference>
    <content>
    </content>
      <p>This is the second paragraph and a lovely one it is too.</p>
      <reference>Donald</reference>
    <content>
    </content>
      <p>This paragraph uses the same reference as paragraph 1.</p>
      <reference>Patrick</reference>
    </content>
  </body>
</article>
```

... would become ...

```
<article>
  <body>
    <p IDREF="ref1">This is the first paragraph.</p>
    <p IDREF="ref2">This is the second paragraph and a lovely one it is too.</p>
    <p IDREF="ref1">This paragraph uses the same reference as paragraph 1.</p>
  </body>
  <references>
    <reference ID="#ref1">Patrick</reference>
    <reference ID="#ref2">Donald</reference>
  </references>
</article>
```

So far I'm failing. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

I would write templates like

```
<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="content/p"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <references>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="content/reference"/>
  </references>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <p id="{generate-id()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reference">
  <reference idref="#{generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[1])}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </reference>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you could use modes to process the `p` elements twice if needed. If wanted then of course instead of using `generate-id` you could generate your own ids with `xsl:number` or `count`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this (haven't tested it too thoroughly):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="kRef" match="reference" use="." />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/article" >
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <references>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//reference[count(. | key('kRef', .)[1]) = 1]" mode="index"/>
    </references>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
<xsl:variable name="myRef" select="following-sibling::reference[1]" />
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="IDREF">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('kRef', $myRef)[1]/preceding::reference)+1" />  
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reference"/>

<xsl:template match="reference" mode="index">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::reference)+1" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result, using your sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
  <body>
    <content>
      <p IDREF="1">This is the first paragraph.</p>
      <content/>
      <p IDREF="2">This is the second paragraph and a lovely one it is too.</p>
      <content/>
      <p IDREF="1">This paragraph uses the same reference as paragraph 1.</p>
    </content>
  </body>
  <references>
    <reference ID="1">Patrick</reference>
    <reference ID="2">Donald</reference>
  </references>
</article>
```

---

Here's a modified version of the above, using auto-generated ids to index the references instead of counting previous occurrences:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="kRef" match="reference" use="." />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/article" >
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <references>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//reference[count(. | key('kRef', .)[1]) = 1]" mode="index"/>
    </references>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
<xsl:variable name="myRef" select="following-sibling::reference[1]" />
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="IDREF">
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(key('kRef', $myRef)[1])" />   
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reference"/>

<xsl:template match="reference" mode="index">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result here will look something like (depending on the processor):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
  <body>
    <content>
      <p IDREF="idm758912">This is the first paragraph.</p>
      <content/>
      <p IDREF="idm251232">This is the second paragraph and a lovely one it is too.</p>
      <content/>
      <p IDREF="idm758912">This paragraph uses the same reference as paragraph 1.</p>
    </content>
  </body>
  <references>
    <reference ID="idm758912">Patrick</reference>
    <reference ID="idm251232">Donald</reference>
  </references>
</article>
```